# PSQL trigger and function pair bug on INSERT

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-insert, plpgsql

I have a table (`time TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY, pressure REAL NOT NULL`). I need to develop a trigger/function pair that does this: if inserting a new entry, either update the existing entry or insert the new entry depending on the timestamp.

The trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_insert();
```

The function method:

```
create or replace function func_insert()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    time_exists TIMESTAMP;
    BEGIN
        IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        SELECT time INTO time_exists FROM mytable WHERE time = NEW.time;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(NEW.*);
    ELSE 
        UPDATE mytable SET pressure = NEW.pressure WHERE time = NEW.time;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

Discussion:

1. Without the `IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN` condition, the script results in depth trigger overflow exception.
2. The problem is that I get an error when inserting the first(sic!) entry into the empty(sic!) table:

   psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_pkey"
   DETAIL:  Key ("time")=(2019-06-01 00:00:00) already exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the row is to be inserted, just return `new` instead of trying to re-insert it again.

If the row is to be updated, don't return `new` else it will be inserted...

That being said, doing an upsert is the cleanest solution

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (time, pressure) VALUES (..., ...)
  ON CONFLICT (time)
    DO UPDATE SET pressure = EXCLUDED.pressure;
```